# Why is my computer name new-host-2.home on the network?

Tags: network

I configured my computer name to "Macbook of Matthieu" in the network sharing preferences.

However, this name end up being used: `new-host-2.home`, how can I change that?

Comment: Sounds like a DHCP generated name.

Comment: Please see this post.. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal

Answer (score 2):

The ".home" domain sounds like it might be something your router is providing. Check your router's settings for a DNS server configuration. If you want to use the Bonjour/mDNS ".local" names, then turn off the router's DNS server, or tell it to act only as a proxy for your ISP's DNS service.

Unfortunately, the specifics of these settings, and even how they are named, vary widely across routers. You will have to look up instructions for your specific router model.

Comment: How? Please be more specific with instructions to do so.

Comment: @MarkA It depends on the router. I have updated my answer to say so.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences, then the Sharing Pane. You can change the name of the computer there.

This sometimes happens when a new computer replaces an old one, or a new version of an OS is installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that is what I did (see my question). However it still is `new-host-2.home`. I'll try to restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at the shared Mac from a Windows machine, the discovery is done through Microsoft Network, which uses NetBIOS layer to get the name of the hosts. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS

The NetBIOS name is set up in OS X from the Network Properties panel, as shown in the image bellow.[image]

If, you are having issues with the name seen under OS X, than you might have a synchronisation name problem, as described in the topic bellow:
[Why does my iMac have one name under sharing, but then say 'new-host3.home' as well?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45483/why-does-my-imac-have-one-name-under-sharing-but-then-say-new-host3-home-as-w)

Answer (score 0):

If your able to find the mac then you wil see its your own the answer you find her: whatismyipaddress.com/ipv4-parts[image]

As you see the mac's are al the same as one of my pc's
You can copy past it in macvendor to find whitch pc