# How do I change the owner name on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, user-account

When I use Terminal my computer says

```
Last login: Thu Jun  7 22:00:00 on ttys000
John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~ John$
```

That was the default account name on the computer when I bought it. I have been using it for 2 weeks now and I am pretty much set with the OS and I really don't want to do a reinstall. I deleted the John Doe account but that did nothing.

How do I change my Terminal so it doesn't display that any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In System Preferences, go to Sharing and change the name at the top of the window.

[image: System Prefs>Sharing>Computer name]

Comment: Perfect mate. For future viewers, quit terminal and then start it again to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and found a fix in a day. If this issue hasn't been resolved, follow these instructions:

If there's no HostName available, what you see is probably coming from the DNS or DHCP server.

Set your HostName with `sudo scutil --set HostName 'yourHostName'`

That should do it.

[Why is my host name wrong at the Terminal prompt when connected to a public WiFi network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi)

Answer (score -1):

Create a new "USER" --  named as you wish.

Move the entire contents of your current

User Folder to the new folder via Drag & Drop.

If you hold down the **Command Key** during

the operation, selected items will be MOVED,

as opposed to copied, aliased, etc.

Reboot while holding down the Option Key.

Voila !

Comment: I think Davisgeek's answer is a bit more practical.