# VPN Changes Hostname

Tags: macos, network, vpn

When I connect to various VPN servers (Windows PPTP, Cisco IPSEC) the hostname of my laptop gets updated.

Is there a setting somewhere that will stop this from happening?

Answer (score 12):

The VPN's DHCP server probably assigns hostname together with the IP address and the computer uses it instead of what you've set during setup and what appears in System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer name.

To set a permanent hostname do 
`sudo scutil --set HostName DesiredHostname` in Terminal.app (there are also ComputerName and LocalHostName that can be changed there).
Restart may be required.

Answer (score 5):

This question is a manifestation of the same situation described in question *[Why is my host name wrong at the Terminal prompt when connected to a public WiFi network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi)*, and the answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127405/17600 explains the cause and the solution.  Copying from that answer:

> Type in Terminal:
>
> ```
> scutil --get HostName
> ```
>
> If there's no HostName available, what you see is probably coming from
>   the DNS or DHCP server.
>
> Set your HostName with:
>
> ```
> sudo scutil --set HostName 'yourHostName'
> ```
>
> That should do it.