# Home folder name changed but terminal prompt is still showing last name

Tags: macos, terminal, system-settings

I changed the name of my home folder in 2 ways. First I change it using the instructions from the official `Apple` website:

[sudo mv /Users/old_name /Users/new_name](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1428)

and then I also changed it going to `System Preferences` > `Users & Groups` > `Advanced Options`.

My problem is that the prompt on the terminal is still showing me the last name I had

```
name-mbp:~ old-home-folder-name$
```

why?

Is it possible to make changes have effect also on the terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my host name wrong at the Terminal prompt when connected to a public WiFi network?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi)

Answer (score 1):

What the terminal prompt is showing you is not the home folder name, but the user name.

The folder is displayed after the machine name, in the ~ highlighted below:

```
name-mbp:~ old-home-folder-name$
Folder   ^ ^ User name
```

You can type the command `pwd` ("print working directory") to see which folder it is currently in. Or you can type the command `echo $HOME` to show you what Terminal thinks your home directory is.