# Hostname incorrectly shown in Terminal and scutil HostName is not set

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal

Today I started the Terminal and the prompt showed:

```
flos-ipad: mareek$
```

Now I'm confused because this is not the Hostname of my MacBook Pro.
Furthermore my name isn't "Flo" and I don't own an iPad. The Username "mareek" is correct for the user I'm logged in to.

I tried

```
$ scutil --get HostName
HostName: not set
$ scutil --get LocalHostName
Macbook-Pro-2
$ scutil --get ComputerName
Macbook-Pro
```

I wonder why the Hostname isn't set, and where the "flos-ipad" comes from?
Any ideas?

Thank you

EDIT: I actually found the solution. [Link - Stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi) /close

Comment: Check in your System Preferences -> sharing how the computer name is named. Usually the LocalHostName and ComputerName should be the same. ComputerName = Using in your local network, LocalHostName = using by Bonjour Network Services and HostName is irrelevant because need only for static IP Addresses and DNS-Server.