# nobody user in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

What's `nobody` phrase in **Terminal** (and **iTerm**)?
[image]

It sometimes changes to my Mac name. But why is it `nobody` and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nobody` is probably the hostname your system gets from a DHCP server. This also explains why sometimes you see the name you set yourself.

Check out [Why is my host name wrong at the Terminal prompt when connected to a public WiFi network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi)