# my hostname is not my laptop name

Tags: macos, terminal, network, system-information

My laptop's hostname appears to be `Georges-MacBook-Pro-Mid-2145.local`,

[image: Computers on your local network can access your computer at: Georges-MacBook-Pro-Mid-2145.local]

```
$ hostname
Georges-MacBook-Pro-Mid-2145.local
```

Why is the number reported here `2145` instead of `2015`? (I own a MacBook Pro Mid-2015, so I was expecting the host name to be `Georges-MacBook-Pro-Mid-2015.local`).

Did I do something wrong somewhere while twiddling about in the terminal or is it normal that the last numbers are... "random" (?)

Comment: It's probably getting that from your local DNS server for some reason; without knowing more it's hard to tell what that reason is. See: [MacOS Strange Terminal Prompt, Tried Resetting Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal).

Comment: The prompt uses the hostname, so the same sources of confusion should apply.

Comment: That's not the point; the point is that the Q&A answer I linked explains why you can get an unexpected hostname; whether you're seeing the weird name via the `hostname` command or via the shell prompt doesn't matter.

Comment: @GordonDavisson it's using my network provider's DNS server I think. So my computer's hostname can change if I went to someone else's house or something? I never knew this

Comment: @theonlygusti "So my computer's hostname can change if I went to someone else's house or something?" No! Your computer's hostname never changes until you tell it to. Your WiFi network / DNS / whatever does not control the hostname.

Comment: @theonlygusti your hostname is a name, for the host, your computer. It does not change based on which network you use. That answer they linked you to has a prompt that's doing some weird stuff that macOS doesn't do on its own.

Comment: The hostname *can be* determined by DNS - if the DNS service has a name associated with your IP address, that overrides what's in the Sharing Preferences. But the screenshot you added shows that the weird name *is* in the Sharing Preferences, which *is not* affected by DNS. Therefore, this is not coming from where I thought it might be. I don't know why it's different, but it should be safe to fix it in the Sharing Preferences.

Comment: @GordonDavisson is it indeed a "weird" name after all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clicking the edit button that's right next to the hostname that you want to edit?

[image: Edit button in action]

Comment: I don't want to change the hostname, at least not until I know why it has this value.

Comment: It has that value because you probably made a typo when setting it up, then changed the computer name, and changing the computer name doesn't change the hostname. It's probably simpler than you think and it has nothing to do with what network you're on.

Comment: "when setting it up" — when would I have manually set up my own hostname?

Comment: @theonlygusti when setting your computer name for the first time? the hostname is set from that... if you made any typo there but then changed it, the hostname would not have changed on its own, you would have to change the hostname manually

Comment: I'm pretty sure I never had to choose my computer's name when setting it up...

Comment: @theonlygusti Then how exactly did it end up with the name `George's MacBook Pro Mid 2015`?

Comment: auto-generated from me setting my username as "George" no?

Comment: @theonlygusti then where did 2145 come from lol... Besides, mine only said "[Name]'s MacBook Pro" when I did first see it so even if you didn't set it, it wouldn't say "Mid 2015"

Answer (score 0):

This question is a manifestation of the same situation described in question *[Why is my host name wrong at the Terminal prompt when connected to a public WiFi network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi)*, and the answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127405/17600 explains the cause and the solution.  Copying from that answer:

> Type in Terminal:
>
> ```
> scutil --get HostName
> ```
>
> If there's no HostName available, what you see is probably coming from
>   the DNS or DHCP server.
>
> Set your HostName with:
>
> ```
> sudo scutil --set HostName 'yourHostName'
> ```
>
> That should do it.