# Terminal-App: What’s in front of colon and why does it change with a different network?

Tags: terminal, mac, network, wifi, router

When I open the terminal-app, there is this default code. However, it changes depending on the network:

This is how it looks like in my local coworking office:

```
Last login: Thu Aug 13 14:49:57 on ttys000
HUAWEI_P20-12345678:~ user$
```

This is how it looks like at home or with wlan disconnected:

```
Last login: Thu Aug 13 14:51:36 on ttys000
MyMac:~ user$
```

I don't know what a HUAWEI P20 should be? I have an iPhone and I can't believe that the coworking office has a cellphone as router?

Did my computer get hacked?

What does this line mean and what difference does it make?

Furthermore, what does ttys000 mean?

btw, MyMac is obviously the name of my computer and I replaced my username with "user".

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What you see in front of the colon is the name of your computer. See this answer for more information: [OS X computer name not matching what shows on terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you see at the beginning of every line of `Terminal` is not a function of the `Terminal` application but a feature of any shell on any Unix system.
This string is defined as PS1 = Prompt String n°1.

On most shell this string is defined as containing your hostname as you can get it with the basic command `hostname`.
Of course, your hostname depend on your method of connection, your ISP, and how your computer name can be established from your DNS servers (Domain Name System).

When your computer doesn't have a connection established to the Internet, this name is its local name as you have defined it in `System Preferences > Sharing > Computer Name:`.

The last component of the line showing you how you connected
the last time you did is the terminal from which you were
connected on your Mac. Each shell session has a virtual terminal on which your shell commands are runs. This is the final part of the terminal name you were using as shown with the command `tty`.

If the `Last login:` information looks right to you, then it means your computer wasn't pirated and used by
a criminal.

Comment: thank you very much! With your answer, I searched for "hostname" and found this further explanation: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi Looks like there was a Huawai P20-cellphone connected with the same ip-adress in this public wifi as I have now. Thus terminal gets the Huawai-name from the DNS-server of the network

Comment: Regarding the tty-command: I searched for it and found this explanation: https://superuser.com/questions/812086/ttysxxx-in-who-command Just wanted to post it for future reference, if anyone finds this topic