# How to change computer name so terminal displays it in Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: sharing, macos, hosts

When I setup my computer I named it "Scott's MacBook Pro". And so when I go to System preferences->Sharing, it says Scott's MacBook Pro there as my computer name. However, opening up a terminal gives me this prompt:

```
Last login: Sun Oct  7 11:02:49 on ttys003
new-host-4:~ scott$
```

When I login to Backblaze, they list my computer as "new‑host‑4_2012_10_07". Did I not fully set my computer name? Should I use the traditional `hostname` command?

Comment: To my knowledge this is what DNS reports it to be.  If your IP-number does not have a name, the name from Preferences is used (perhaps the `.local` domain))

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - my .local domain from the Sharing preferences has been scotts-macbook-pro.local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't do anything to my computer, but eventually for some reason the hostname and computer name all registered as the name I initially set! In fact I had the following terminal open the whole time and this is exactly a cut and paste:

```
new-host-4:~ scott$ hostname
new-host-4.home
new-host-4:~ scott$ hostname
Scotts-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Answer (score 396):

If you use:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName name-you-want
```

it will work a bit better. From the scutil(8) man page:

> ```
> --get pref
>     Retrieves the specified preference.  The current value will be
>     reported on standard output.
>
>     Supported preferences include:
>           ComputerName   The user-friendly name for the system.
>           LocalHostName  The local (Bonjour) host name.
>           HostName       The name associated with hostname(1) and gethostname(3).
>
> --set pref [newval]
>     Updates the specified preference with the new value.  If the new value is not
>     specified on the command line then it will be read from standard input.
>
>     Supported preferences include: ComputerName LocalHostName HostName
>
>     The --set option requires super-user access.
> ```

Comment: Worked for me after running that command and rebooting Terminal.

Comment: Worked as charm

Comment: This works for me, but upon rebooting, it then resets the hostname in the terminal back to what it was prior to me changing it.

Comment: Works in Mojave. The terminal was showing `emulator02` even though I changed it in settings -- or tried. I just ran all three supported preferences and restarted terminal; now I can get the hostname right.

Answer (score 170):

After following [Jeffrey J. Hoover's tip](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53042/40119),

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "newname"
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "newname"
sudo scutil --set HostName "newname"
```

I would add these last two steps.

- Flush the DNS cache by typing:
  `dscacheutil -flushcache`
- Restart your Mac.

EDIT: It didn't work for me until I restarted my mac.

Comment: Are you a former Windows user, carrying over the practice of rebooting after every little change, or do you actually have evidence that it's necessary to restart?

Comment: @iconoclast  Last used Windows primarily in 2004. Restarting worked for me and 16 other people.  Wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Meaning it didn't work until you restarted?  (Restarting ***can*** hurt when you actually do serious work on your computer, and therefore have lots of applications open.  Getting everything back how you had it before reboot can be a *****.) Also, the fact that 16 people found some part of your answer helpful doesn't mean nothing worked until they restarted.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work until I restarted. Thanks for the info; didn't know it can be harmful.

Comment: Worked for me without restarting, just quit Terminal completely and re-open.

Comment: I first used `scutil --get` to discover that `ComputerName` and `LocalHostName` had been correctly set by using System Preferences (Sharing). However, it told me that `HostName` was `not set`. Thus, I just used `sudo scutil --set` in order to set `HostName`. Then, I didn't need to use `dscacheutil` or do a reboot as immediately a check of `hostname` showed that things were fixed for me and opening a new Terminal tab showed my prompt was now fixed too. (OS X 10.9.4)

Comment: You shouldn't even need to restart terminal to reflect the changes, just source the configuration responsible for your prompt.

Comment: Why should we flush the DNS cache?

Answer (score 58):

For those who are not looking for a command line solution, you can change it under

```
System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name:
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The name at terminal command prompt still remained as `localhost`

Comment: Did you restart the terminal?

Comment: I defs had to restart Terminal, but this was the easiest method.

Comment: This did not work for me because Terminal kept showing the old name. But, John's answer did solve it - on Mojave.

Comment: Catalina requires a reboot after following procedure.  Renaming host successful

Comment: This is the easiest and best solution. It just requires a restart once you're done

Comment: Yep this is best, took 10 seconds, re-opened a new terminal window

Answer (score 27):

You can define what you want to see before the `$` in your terminal by modifying the file `~/.profile`.

For example if you add to the file `~/.profile` the following line:

```
# h is the host name, w the complete path 
export PS1="\h:\w$ "
```

you will see the host name and the complete path of the current directory:

```
host_name:current_directory_path$
```

You can also modify my example by using the following options in the export command:

```
\d – Current date
\t – Current time
\h – Host name
\# – Command number
\u – User name
\W – Current working directory (i.e: Desktop/)
\w – Current working directory, full path (i.e: /Users/Admin/Desktop)
```

Comment: Why -1? He said that he cannot see its host name in the Terminal.

Comment: wasn't me with the -1 :). Thank you for your answer, I guess I'm not just looking for how to change my name in the terminal, but clearly my computer is still referenced by the new-host-4 ugly name as services like Backblaze use it. My previous MacBook Pro had a nicer name that I chose, I don't know why my mountain lion MacBook Pro isn't using the name I have in the Sharing preferences

Answer (score 14):

You can run

```
sudo hostname Name-Of-My-Computer
```

in Terminal to change the name.

Comment: The man page for hostname says to run `scutil --set HostName name-of-host` if you want to keep the hostname across reboots

Comment: For me it worked very well, even restarting the computer. Thank You.

Comment: This worked for me after I restarted my Mac (running El Capitan)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I found that it was a problem with our DNS server, as the reverse DNS lookup didn't scavenge because there was duplicate DNS entries for the IP address and hostname.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding an answer here because I have recently run into this problem as well.

In OSX 10.7.4 and possibly prior, there appears to be a bug in the Edit Hostname option in the Sharing preference panel.  It sets the hostname to the last thing set instead of the current this set.

I had to run `sudo hostname [preferred hostname]` in order to set it correctly, after setting it in Sharing.