# Terminal shows hostname from old machine, not new machine

Tags: mac, terminal, migration, macos

Right now I have a Mac Mini. I migrated macbook pro data from a time machine, but I didn't do it from the beginning of my startup. I used the migration assistance to migrate the data. However, I'm getting my macbook pro name in my terminal command line, why is that?

```
Name-Macbook-Pro:~ name$
```

Why am i getting this? I'm on my Mac Mini, I guess its from the migration but will it affect anything else? How do I change this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That part of the prompt is the hostname (\h) by default. Normally changing the computer name from System Preferences also changes the hostname:

[image]

The settings are stored in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`:

```
<key>Network</key>
<dict>
    <key>HostNames</key>
    <dict>
        <key>LocalHostName</key>
        <string>Lauris-iMac</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>System</key>
<dict>
    <key>ComputerName</key>
    <string>Lauri’s iMac</string>
    <key>ComputerNameEncoding</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
```

This changes the system hostname:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName My-MacMini
```

It adds `<key>HostName</key><string>My-MacMini</string>` under `System`. If the system hostname has been set, changing the computer name or local hostname from System Preferences won't change the prompt.

Comment: +1; I conclude that there's no good reason to ever set `HostName` (despite what `man hostname` says!), given that its value is then out of sync with the `LocalHostName` value set via System Preferences. Conversely, `LocalHostName` _is_ also recognized by `hostname`. To put it another way: if you want to change the hostname from a shell, use BOTH `sudo scutil --set LocalHostName newName` and `sudo scutil --set ComputerName newName`, where the `ComputerName` value can be a friendlier version (spaces, punctuation) of the `LocalHostName` value (alphanumerics and dashes only).

Comment: To get rid of a `HostName` entry, set its value to an empty string (this effectively removes the key from the `.plist` file): `sudo scutil --set HostName ''`.