# How can i reset my Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, osx-server

just some time ago i installed the OS X Server app on my mac and since this day it always appears `server` as the chosen directory in my terminal.

But because i dont really like the Server application i just removed it but the `server` in my terminal is still left. 
So i wonder now how i can get the default back like `users/...`

I am running mountain lion on my mac.

I am a real newby to both mac and usage of terminal but i need it know for some work and i just get errors every time i am trying to enter something.

Comment: what does `echo $HOME` returns ? Or maybe you have something in you .profile or your .bashrc_profile that changes the Default Working Directory.

Comment: If the full prompt is like `server:~ username$`, you can [change the hostname](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88463). If it's just `server` or something, check your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: echo home returns /Users/username

Comment: What does running `pwd` show?

Comment: `pwd` returns the same `/Users/username`

Comment: @swe19 — No, `echo home` certainly does not return `/Users/username`, it does return `home`. Computers are delicate and picky.

Answer (score 7):

Goto your **HomeFolder -> Library -> Preferences** and delete the file : *com.apple.terminal.plist*

That should reset the settings on your Terminal

Comment: I can not find the terminal.plist i.e. it does not exist in my preferences libary

Comment: From the Finder menu bar, select **Go ▹ Go to Folder** and copy the following line into the text box that opens:
   


~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist

Comment: I removed it but it does not change anything. Tried to even reboot after removing and install+uninstall the server app but nothing changes.

Comment: The file is `com.apple.Terminal.plist`.

Answer (score 2):

*Since you have mentioned that running `pwd` shows a path not mentioning `server`, I believe you are mistaking `server` for being the directory when it is actually the hostname.*

OS X Server will change your hostname (by default) to `server.<name>.private`, so Terminal will show `server:~ username$` (in Bash with the default prompt).

To change the hostname, you can use the following command:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName yourhostname
```

<sup>Replace *yourhostname* with your preferred hostname</sup>

Comment: This is a way better solution, tried everything delete `plist`, `ps1` but this did the trick. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

System terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Terminal
```

iTerm2:

```
defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2
```