# Terminal window is now blank

Tags: macos, terminal

A Terminal newbie here.

I had downloaded and installed Git, but when I typed "Git --version" I would get illegal instruction. I tried to uninstall Git and now my Terminal window in blank.

How do I get Name$ as a prompt again?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: How did You remove Git?
Here's link for changing command prompt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416274/how-to-suppress-or-customize-mac-terminal-shell-prompt

Comment: Share a screenshot ? You could reset the terminal if nothing works - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91381/how-can-i-reset-my-terminal/91396#91396

Comment: @JashJacob I deleted my com.apple.Terminal.plist but still no prompt in the Terminal window.Thanks for you help.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I ran the uninstall Git script and now my Terminal window is blank. I used to get the prompt "Elia$". Now I literally have a blank screen. What is a string of characters I can type in the Terminal window? I am totally new to Terminal and command lines. Thank you!

Comment: @Elia try this: `echo "export PS1=\"\u\w$\"" >> ~/.bash_profile` and restart Your Terminal app.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Unfortunately, I still gat a blank screen. I am typing "echo "export PS1=\"\u\w$\"" >> ~/.bash_profile" and hit return. Nothing is returned after I enter that command line. Thank you.

Comment: Can you type anything?
Try pressing both control and c in the keyboard
If yes, it must be the .bash_profile