# What file permissions do I need to change after 10.8.3 restore?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, permission, migration

My 08 mb, OSX Mt Lion, crashed so I bought new 2012 MBPr. Luckily, I backed everything up.  Migrated everything from 08mb over to new MBPr.  I noticed that when I deleted files, it skipped the trash can.  My home folder did not have me as admin with RW permissions so I had to add myself and give myself RW access.

Before, when I opened iTerm (similar to Terminal), it would say `computer name:~ username$`. Now, I see an odd hexadecimal name for my computer.

How do I change the hexadecimal code to my computer name?

[image: 2012 MBPr after migration assistant]

Is this the correct default permissions for Home folder?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you repaired Permissions already?

Comment: If you go the "sharing" preference pane, it allows you to set a name to your computer. Have you tried that and checking in iTerm?

Comment: I have repaired permissions. Just changed name of computer in "Sharing" to something else and it still shows that weird `unknown20c9d....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my issue was resolved here: [OS X computer name not matching what shows on terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal/90874#90874)

1. `sudo scutil --set ComputerName "newname"`
2. `sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "newname"`
3. `sudo scutil --set HostName "newname"`
4. Flush the DNS cache by typing: `dscacheutil -flushcache`
5. Restart your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The home folder is supposed to be owned by the user:

```
$ ls -l /Users/
total 0
drwxrwxrwt   6 root   wheel   204 Apr 13 23:28 Shared
drwxr-xr-x@ 53 lauri  staff  1802 May 11 18:00 lauri
```

[image]

If there are further issues, you could try running `sudo chown $USER ~` or [resetting home folder permissions and ACLs from the recovery partition](http://pondini.org/OSX/Password.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Very helpful.  It hung up on resetting so I had to quit it after a few hours.  Still worked though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. It sorted itself out after I rebooted the machine and also my wireless router--so I can't obviously know which of the two actually fixed the problem. BUT, this does suggest to me steps (4) and (5) of your solution might be sufficient to solve the problem if you've already named the computer in System Preferences.