# What side effects, if any, are there from issuing scutil --set HostName 'Fred'?

Tags: network, dns, bonjour

I have read that you can change all of the three "computer names" associated with a Mac using the `scutil` utility.

The three names in question are `ComputerName` (the "friendly" name), `LocalHostName` (used only by Bonjour) and `HostName` (which is subsequently returned by `/bin/hostname`).

I understand that there are very few side effects from setting the first two.  Obviously if Bonjour clients are out there looking for the old `LocalHostName` then changing it will be a drag from their perspective, but otherwise this seems pretty side effect free.

I am no networking guru so the idea of changing what is reported by `/bin/hostname` is a bit spooky to me.  Should I be concerned?

For more background, what is reported by `/bin/hostname` changes, it seems, currently, with the weather.

Suppose, for example, my `ComputerName` is `Chuggid` (don't ask).  Suppose my `LocalHostName` is also `Chuggid`.

I've found that when I connect to some wifi hotspots, `hostname` returns `chuggid.linksys`.  When I am connected to my workplace's VPN, `hostname` returns things like `xyz-abc.vpnpool.yoyodyne.com`.

So my worry stems from the fact that I'm concerned that since I didn't come up with either of these names, when I arbitrarily decide to set my `HostName` to `chuggid` that this will cause all sorts of problems.

Is it "safe" to change all three Mac "computer names" to whatever I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already set the `HostName` yourself using `scutil`, `/bin/hostname` is probably reporting the result of a reverse DNS lookup on your computer's IP address. Both the IP address and the result of the reverse DNS lookup will likely differ based on the network you're connected to, and can easily change over time on the same network, too.

`scutil --set HostName foo` is a persistent setting, and unlike `LocalHostName` and `ComputerName`, `HostName` cannot be set in the GUI. For that reason, some advise against setting `HostName`. In my opinion, as long as you don't get confused if you try to make changes through the GUI later, setting your `HostName` is unlikely to cause any negative side effects for you. However, if you do run into issues, it's [easy to undo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/129674/112297) with `scutil --set HostName ''`.