# Why does my command line prompt now beging with "vpn"?

Tags: terminal, osx-server, vpn

I was just (unsuccessfully) playing around with setting up a vpn in OS X Server, and now all my new terminal prompts begin with "vpn" followed by my user name. Anyone know why this is the case and how I can revert back to my default prompt, without "vpn"?

Answer (score 1):

[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/357159/osx-terminal-showing-incorrect-hostname) has a similar question/answer.  <strike>I thought this was covered here already, but couldn't find it.</strike>

[Found it!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

As you were setting up the vpn it got changed.

That can be changed in System preferences - Sharing - Computer Name.

Use Edit to change the name to your liking.

[image: sharing]

First it shows the Machine name, then your user name.

In my case `myMBA:~ Buscar$`