# change name in mac os terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I just bought new macbook pro, and opened up my terminal .

it shows:

(base) Jiui-MacBookPro:~ myname$
I want to change that "Jiui" part that is located in front of -MacBookPro.

How can I do that? I know how to change that "myname" part but don't know in front of that macbookpro.

Please save me :(

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Check the accepted answer to this question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal for a way to change the name. For example, this command: `sudo scutil --set HostName JHP-MacBookPro ` would change the prompt to `JHP-MacBookPro: ~ myname$`. Note that you will be asked to type your password when you run the command.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the "Sharing" system preference pane you will see a field at the top that allows you to change the computer name. Click the lock at bottom left of the window and when prompted enter your password and you will be able to edit the field.

[image]