# Why does my Mac have multiple names?

Tags: mac, macos

When I got my Mac seven years ago and configured it, I picked a name for it. That was the name I saw everywhere. However, now I'm seeing one of two names, depending on where I look:

- In System Preferences > Sharing, I see the name I originally selected for my computer (let's call this "name 1").
- In Terminal, it was changed to the first four letters of name 1 followed by MBPtina2014 (presumably a shortening of "MacBook Pro Retina 2014, which my computer is") (let's call this "name 2"). I changed this with `sudo scutil --set HostName [name 1]`.
- Whenever I look at my computer from an external device (e.g. in my internet router's list of connected devices or on another computer I'm sharing my Steam library with), I see name 2. This is despite the computer's name being configured to name 1 in System Preferences, as mentioned above.
- In Terminal, if I type `scutil --get ComputerName`, I get name 1. If I type `scutil --get LocalHostName`, I get a version of name 1 without spaces or special characters, which is fine.

I have no idea when or why it changed to name 2 in some places. More importantly, I have no idea how to bring it back to name 1 *everywhere*.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30552/120171

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't. I'd already come aross that answer, which is why I knew you could do `sudo scutil --set HostName [name 1]` in the first place. My hostname (which was previously name 2) is now correctly showing as name 1, but I still see name 2 in other places.

Comment: Ok understood. Good to know