# Mac Os X Hacked? Unknown Username in Terminal!

Tags: security, bash

I recently noticed an unusual "username" appearing in my Terminal window.
Usually when I open Terminal I see something like this:

**Ryans-MacBook-Pro:~ ryan$**

But recently when I've logged on I see this:

**GIS-NicoDellLaptop:~ ryan$**

This is quite strange to me, and I don't remember seeing it before. I don't know anyone named Nico, and I don't own a Dell laptop.

If I turn off my internet, and run the command **"exit bash"**, then I open a new Terminal window, I see what is expected: Ryans-MacBook-Pro:~ ryan$

Yet, as soon as I connect to the internet, when I open a Terminal window, I again see:
**GIS-NicoDellLaptop:~ ryan$**

If I **"exit bash"** again and open a new terminal window, it stays there. I can only get rid of it by using **"exit bash"** if I'm disconnected from the internet.

---

Remote Login, Screen Sharing, Remote Management are OFF.

Using this command: **dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_'**

I see that there aren't any new users that have been created on the system.

**However I do see over 800 entries in the system.log file related to GIS-NicoDellLap**.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Ryan

Comment: This is normal; confusing, but normal. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal/42498088#42498088) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal).

Comment: Yep, that is confusing. I understand how that can happen now. Thanks very much