# What should the name of the startup volume be in finder and when would it be recreated?

Tags: disk-volume

This is a bit of a strange question but I just want to see if I should be concerned as I do play around with... "not yet mainstream"... open source software programs and am always slightly concerned that I may unexpectedly download something dangerous.

What should the name of the startup volume be in the finder? Mine is currently untitled.

When would it ever be recreated? I've had this computer for a several years and it says it was created on July 15. I may have ran a operating system update around then so that may not be concerning.

The reason I am concerned is because I noticed in my terminal that the computer's name was someone elses for a period of time. In the title bar of the terminal it said `my-user@serenas-MPS` and then I restarted the terminal and it showed up as `my-user@MyNames-MacBook-Pro-2` which looks normal but I don't remember the `-2` aspect of it from before.

Comment: Finder doesn’t have a startup volume.  A volume name is assigned when you create the volume itself.  Renaming it cannot be done unless you unmount it first.  The name you see on your prompt is your hostname and that’s an entirely different thing.  What exactly are you trying to diagnose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OS X computer name not matching what shows on terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal) The boot volume name is whatever you call it. Mine is called KickMeHard [All my boot drives for 30 years have had some oblique reference to 'booting' or kicking' ;) @Allan - btw, you can change the name on the fly, right from the Finder, same as any file/folder [or at least can in Mojave & earlier].