Strange $HOST showing in iTerm
I am running macOS 14.5 on an M2 Macbook Air, and use ZSH for my shell environment with iTerm2.
I have a guest staying with me (let's call him Ricardo), who only has an iPad here.  When I opened up iTerm2 today on my macbook (after not having used iterm for about a month), I noted that my prompt, which usually would say myname@localhost now says myname@RicardomanasiPad instead.
If I type echo $HOST, I get RicardomanasiPad.localdomain
I can't fathom why my host would reflect someone else's name and iPad when they have had no access to my computer, and only have access to the WiFi network for internet access.
Is this some strange Mac behaviour, or is something nefarious going on?

Probably the same issue as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal .

It may look like it, but it's not the same problem.
