# Why does my iMac have one name under sharing, but then say 'new-host3.home' as well?

Tags: macos, sharing, domain

In Sharing, my iMac is called 'iMac Quad'. But right below it, its now saying new-host-3.home as well.

[image: sharing]

This also appears that it would then be on two domains - .local and .home.

How do I correct this? If I change the computer name, it won't change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the computer name and host name can get out of sync.  Open a terminal window and use

```
sudo hostname <new hostname>
```

to change the hostname.  Once executed, it changes the system configuration, so the new hostname will be there when you reboot.

Also, be aware that some DHCP servers will assign a hostname.  Depending on the network you attach to and the DHCP server configuration you may have to work with the network administrator if you need to use a different hostname.  You don't have to worry about this for most consumer grade routers.

Comment: This is on a home computer, with a Verizon FiOS router and then an Airport Extreme. I am familiar with hostname, just trying to find out how to trace what happened here.

Comment: @jmlumpkin I haven't figured out the sequence of events that occurs that causes them to diverge.  They are used for different things, so while OS X seems to make an effort to keep them the same, it doesn't force them to be the same, and I suppose there are situations where one might want them to diverge.

Comment: I finally got a chance to do this. I think part of the hostname was due to some network changes I was doing to test Find My Mac. And then I found the config in my router for the domain.